# How to run a command for each line in a bash file?

Tags: bash

I run this

```
php --version | grep -m1 -i php
/usr/bin/php --version | grep -m1 -i php 
python3 --version | grep python 
python --version | grep python 
node --version | grep  node 
npm --version | grep npm 
composer --version | grep composer 
pip3 --version | grep pip 
ruby --version | grep  ruby 
bower --version | grep bower 
gulp --version | grep gulp 
brew --version 
redis-server --version | grep redis 
redis-cli --version | grep redis
```

And I get this, which doesn't run it for all the lines

```
➜  Desktop bash versions.sh 
PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug  6 2019 23:17:07) ( NTS )
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 20:30:32) 
Python 2.7.10
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
Homebrew 2.1.11
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 15f5d; last commit 2019-09-11)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 0960b; last commit 2019-09-11)
redis-cli 5.0.5
➜  Desktop
```

Comment: Maybe some of those lines had no output, or didn't match the grep expression. For example, `python --version` outputs "Python ..." with an upper case P.

Comment: Try to add 2>&1 before the pipe simbols, in order to match both standard output and standard error, and be sure about what you expect from the command. The composer command, for example, won't match "composer", since the output is "Composer [...]". You fix this and maybe other by adding the -i option to grep:
composer  --version 2>&1 | grep -i composer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `read` loop, you can use `xargs`:

```sh
<yourfile.txt xargs -n 1 sh -c '"$0" --version 2>&1 | grep "$0"'
```

- `<yourfile.txt xargs`: distribute the content of `yourfile.txt` as one argument at a time to the following command.
- `-n 1`: One argument at a time.
- `sh -c`: The command is an `sh` shell with `-c` executing an inline script.
- `'"$0" --version  2>&1 | grep "$0"'`: The inline shell script:

  - `"$0" --version`: Execute the argument value provided by `xargs` from your file, as a command name.
  - `2>&1`: Redirect `stderr` to `stdout` to deal with commands printing their version to `stderr`.
  - `| grep "$0"`: Pipe to grep and search the argument value as text.

Comment: Two things I'm wondering: a) why is `xargs` better than `read`? and b) how do you deal with it if not all commands have a `--version` switch?

Comment: It is more efficient to offload the logic to commands especially with loops and reading information from files rather than processing with shell. `xargs` will read the file, parse it and pass arguments using its native compiled C code. It is much better than having Bash interpret all its `while`, `read`, parsing into line variable, evaluating interpretation of the loop exit condition and redoing this for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks Léa! Do I assume correctly and it's better/more efficient to change all loops to `xargs` where possible? Or is that specific to the case of processing lines of a file?

Comment: As a Rule-of-thumb: If one command can replace multiple shell statements, then go for the command. (shell loops count as multiple statements on its own and both the condition and inner commands groups are re-evaluated and re-parsed at each iteration).

Comment: Did you guys even understand what's being asked in the OP? I didn't

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
while read -r LINE
do
    $LINE
done < your_file_name_here
```

You might want to check if all outputs go to `STDOUT`, `python2 --version` and `python3 --version`, for example, exhibit different behavior there.

EDIT 1: As Bayou pointed out it's more efficient to use `done << your_file_name_here`, adjusted accordingly.
EDIT 2: As Benjamin pointed out it should be `<` rather than `<<`, the latter would be useful for a HEREDOC.

Comment: Good comment, except you should change it to `done << your_file_name_here` to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: `<<` won't work here, it has to be just `<`.

Comment: Also, I don't think this answer addresses the part of the question where not all lines seem to have been executed, which is more likely due to some of the output being on standard error instead of standard output.

Comment: @Benjamin W: I adressed that specifically. Not sure about `<<` vs `<`. Off the top of my head I believe it has to be the former, but can't verify that right now.

Comment: Ah, yes, you pointed that out. As for `<<` vs `<`, it's the latter. `<<` is used for here documents.

Answer (score 0):

**This might not be a direct answer to my question but posting anyway**

I found my mistake and I wasn't particularly doing anything wrong. Except, I missed out on `-m1 i` which gets the first line from the output, with case insensitive match.

I did the below and it works fine. I can run it using `bash versions.sh`. Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction.

```
echo -n "php: "; php --version | grep -m1 -i php
echo -n "php56: "; /usr/bin/php --version | grep -m1 -i php 
echo -n "python3: ";python3 --version | grep -m1 -i python 
echo -n "python: "; python --version | grep -m1 -i python 
echo -n "node: ";node --version 
echo -n "npm: ";npm --version
echo -n "composer: ";composer --version | grep -m1 -i composer 
echo -n "pip3: ";pip3 --version | grep -m1 -i pip 
echo -n "ruby: ";ruby --version | grep -m1 -i ruby 
echo -n "bower: "; bower --version 
echo -n "gulp: ";gulp --version 
echo -n "brew: ";brew --version | grep -m1 -i brew 
echo -n "redis-server: ";redis-server --version | grep -m1 -i redis 
echo -n "redis-cli: ";redis-cli --version | grep -m1 -i redis
echo -n "laravel: ";laravel --version
echo -n "vapor: "; vapor --version
echo -n "valet: "; valet --version
```